# Where should the ground screw go for my dryer connection?

Tags: grounding, dryer

I am putting a 4 prong cord on a new dryer and I’ve spent an hour looking for a hole for the grounding screw to go into and I can’t find it.  As far as I can see there is no hole for the grounding screw where the diagram says it should be.  See pics below.  I am moving the strain relief so you can see better.  The black things are not holes. They are the back ends of screws for lack of a better term. Any suggestions? Make a hole myself? If so, how?

[image]

Comment: according to that drawing the strain relief saddle is on the wrong side of the cable hole.  are there strain relief holes hidden under that label?

Comment: According to code, you need to follow directions of the instructions.  Placing the strain relief the right way will probably answer your question for you.

Comment: Put the clamp on the correct side of the plate and give us a focused photo, please.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to tell from the small picture, but does the strain relief screw into the metal housing, or is it free-standing?  If it screws into the metal housing, you could probably just put the ground lug underneath the strain relief and it would attach to the housing that way.  Otherwise, you probably would need to drill a hole and then use a self-tapping ground screw from any decent hardware or electrical supply vendor/store and to fasten the ground lug to the housing.

Or, if you kept the ground screw from the original ground strap, is there enough length in the ground wire to attach it to the housing where the ground screw originally was, and run the ground wire above the white neutral (if there's enough space to provide a good distance between the ground strap metal and the neutral screw).

Comment: Yeah, just use one of the screws holding the strain bracket.

Comment: Note that "self-tapping ground screws" are a thing, but you'll need to order a specific part number for them, namely the Garvin GSST (most self-tappers are coarse pitch sheet metal screws that don't get enough thread into the material to be legal for grounding -- the GSST is a 10-32 UNF, though, and doesn't have that problem as a result)